# do i really need an index in my table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table called `brute` to account the errors during login and stuff and prevent brute force attacks showing a captcha.

it has the fields: `domain`, `ip`, `time`

- Deletions are based in the `time` field. **ex:** delete all entries older than 1 day.
- Selections takes all three columns to detect a possible attack. **ex:** 5 entries (errors) of ip xxxx in login in less than 10 minutes.

The question is: do I really need an index (primary or not)? Some friends are telling me i need but it just feels unnecessary.

`obs: I've stumbled in similar questions around here. Although helpful, they couldn't solve my question entirely for this case.` thank you (:

Comment: Indexing is used to ensure reads are performant. If you have small tables, indexing them will make little difference. What is your issue with defining indexes? If you have large amounts of data in your tables, they should help performance.

Comment: it's not an issue. i just want to understand before adding random indexes. i guess indexes are not "cost free", and if they're not going to help i didn't want to add them for no reason.

Comment: You should _never_ randomly add indexes. You need to consider usage, what columns would end up using the indexes and of course, test before and after applying them to see if the help or make things worse.

Comment: If you don't have the indexes as the server would "like" them, he will create them on the spot, loosing time instead of gaining. In your case: If you have thousands of rows, they will probably be all in memory buffers, so search is fast. If you have millions, better put an index on at least the most discriminating of the 3 fields, i.e. time, limiting search to the rows of the last 10 minutes

Comment: @Martin nice! if you post this as an answer i will accept it :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what Oded mentioned, if the site is going to be internet facing (which it looks like it will be), I suggest you adding indexes as that table might become very, very big. Specially after a few of the nasty things on the internet crawl your site and start trying to guess a login.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the reorganization of an index (B-Tree) on bulk delete operations might be more expensive than the sequential scan. Íf performance becomes an issue you should try to add an index and measure the required time. Without an index all data has to be read and filtered (by the where-clause, sequential-scan) but without additional costs.
 for reorganizing the index.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the number of index on your table will indeed increase write performance.

The question is, will the queries you do be helped by an index - and this depends on several things:

- The size of your table
- The time requirement of said queries
- Whether or not the queries would be helped by an index

I would suggest taking a sample table and running tests. use `EXPLAIN` to help understand how your indexes are being used.

Comment: Not for writes - only for reads, and that's debatable for very small t ables. (unless the write is conditional, of course). If you do an `INSERT` into a table, there's nothing that an index can do to help you, and the indexes need to be updated, so there *is* overhead there. Please know that I'm not condoning abandoning all indexes, and I do strongly believe that every table *should* have a primary key, but I'm answering the question without injecting too much of my my personal opinions.

Comment: @Doug Kress why should i add a primary key in all tables? how would it help in my brute table for instance? i just don't see the point...

Comment: Primary index helps describe what a record is, and without it, the record becomes undefinable (duplicate entries might occur). However, on 'logging' tables, this becomes less relavent, as every field in the table essentially is the identifier. And if every field is identical, that may be an acceptable state.  Bottom line, it's primarily a design concept, and there are always exceptions to the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in general you should index the columns you sort, query, update and delete by.